# See an index.jade file on a browser

Tags: pug

Does anybody know how can I see a `.jade` file on my browser?

I think I understand the concept behind it, but I just can't find answers clear enough to me, or in other words a completely beginners' guide.

I will appreciate if someone can help me with this and give some steps to follow.

Comment: can you expand "see a .jade file on my browser" because it open to interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, Jade is just a preprocessor to HTML.  That means that when a user requests to view a page, the server "renders" the Jade into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert you .jade file into html to see in the browser or use a framework like express. A simple solution is to use the jade build for Sublime text (https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Jade%20Build) or use a service like http://html2jade.com/ to convert you html into jade or jade into html.